# The Sachdev-Ye-Kitaev (SYK) model and conformal $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ symmetry in 0+1D

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, conformal-field-theory, greens-functions, correlation-functions

Two-point function in SYK model is given by
$$\begin{align}
G_{ij}(\tau,\tau')=\frac{b}{|\tau-\tau'|^{1/2}}{\rm sgn}(\tau-\tau')\delta_{ij}
\end{align} \tag{1}$$
where $i$ and $j$ are the indices of the fermion $\chi_i, \chi_j$ and $b$ is just coefficient. SYK model has the following reparametrization invariants in IR limit.
$$\begin{align}
G_{ij}(\tau,\tau')=|f'(\tau)f'(\tau')|^{1/4}G_{ij}(f(\tau),f(\tau'))
\end{align} \tag{2}$$
where $f(\tau)$ is reparametrization of time $\tau$. Several papers have argued that it has only $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ symmetry. I would like to prove this, but I'm not sure how to do it. The $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ transformation can be written as the following transformation.
$$\begin{align}
f(\tau)=\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d},\ a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R},\ ad-bc=1.
\end{align} \tag{3}$$
If we consider this based on the reparametrization invariance mentioned earlier,
$$\begin{align}
G_{ij}(\tau,0)&=|f'(\tau)f'(0)|^{1/4}\frac{b}{|f(\tau)-f(0)|^{1/2}}{\rm sgn}(f(\tau)-f(0))\delta_{ij}\nonumber \\
&=\left|\frac{1}{d(c\tau+d)}\right|^{1/2}\frac{b}{\left|\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}-\frac{b}{d}\right|^{1/2}}{\rm sgn}\left(\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}-\frac{b}{d}\right)\delta_{ij}\nonumber \\
&=\left|\frac{1}{d(c\tau+d)}\right|^{1/2}\frac{b}{\left|\frac{\tau(ad-bc)}{d(c\tau+d)}\right|^{1/2}}{\rm sgn}\left(\frac{\tau(ad-bc)}{d(c\tau+d)}\right)\delta_{ij}\nonumber \\
&=\frac{b}{\left|\tau\right|^{1/2}}{\rm sgn}\left(\frac{\tau}{d(c\tau+d)}\right)\delta_{ij}
\end{align}\tag{4}$$
where I used the fact $$f'(\tau)=\frac{1}{(c\tau+d)^2}>0.\tag{5}$$
But here the sgn function does not become sgn$(\tau)$. Depending on the sign of $d(c\tau+d)$, it can be positive or negative in general. However, many papers claim that it is invariant under $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. What am I doing wrong? Please tell me.

Comment: Because $f'(\tau)=\frac{1}{(c\tau+d)^2}>0$, if $\tau_1>\tau_2$, then $f(\tau_1)>f(\tau_2)$.

Comment: Thanks Youran. However, $ct+d$ diverges at $t=-d/c$. For example, if $f(t)=\frac{2t+1}{t+1}$, this is indeed monotonically increasing, but $\lim_{t\rightarrow -1/2-0} f(t)$ is $\infty$ and  $\lim_{t\rightarrow -1/2+0} f(t)$ is $-\infty$. Therefore, it does not necessarily mean that it will continue to grow. In the previous example, $f(-2)>f(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The connected 2-point function in the [SYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachdev%E2%80%93Ye%E2%80%93Kitaev_model) model is$^1$
   $$G(\tau,\tau^{\prime})~\propto~\frac{{\rm sgn}(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime})}{|\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}|^{2\Delta}}, \tag{1'}$$
   cf. Refs. 1-3.
2. *Proposal.*  The 2-point function (1') becomes invariant under [Moebius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)
   $$\begin{align} f(\tau)~=~&\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d},\tag{3'}  
   \cr f^{\prime}(\tau)~\stackrel{(3')}{=}~&\frac{1}{(c\tau+d)^2}~>~0, \tag{5'}
   \cr a,b,c,d~\in~\mathbb{R},
   \end{align} $$
   with the [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R))
   $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})\cong SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\{\pm {\bf 1}_{2\times 2}\}$
   where
   $$ SL(2,\mathbb{R})~=~\left\{ M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b \cr c&d\end{pmatrix}\in GL(2,\mathbb{R}) ~\mid~ \det(M)= 1 \right\}. \tag{6'}$$
   if we modify the 1D conformal transformation rule (2) to$^2$
   $$\begin{align} G(\tau,\tau^{\prime})~\to~&\color{red}{{\rm sgn}(\sqrt{f^{\prime}(\tau)})}|f^{\prime}(\tau)|^{\Delta}~\color{red}{{\rm sgn}(\sqrt{f^{\prime}(\tau^{\prime})})}|f^{\prime}(\tau^{\prime})|^{\Delta}~G(f(\tau),f(\tau^{\prime}))\tag{2'}\cr
   ~=~&\color{red}{{\rm sgn}(c\tau+d)}|c\tau+d|^{-2\Delta}~\color{red}{{\rm sgn}(c\tau^{\prime}+d)}|c\tau^{\prime}+d|^{-2\Delta}~G(f(\tau),f(\tau^{\prime})),\tag{4'}\end{align} $$
   where we have picked the following branch of the square root:
   $$ \sqrt{f^{\prime}(\tau)}~:=~\frac{1}{c\tau+d}, \tag{7'} $$
   cf. [modular forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form). To prove eq. (4') we have used that
   $$ f(\tau)-f(\tau^{\prime})~\stackrel{(3')}{=}~\frac{\tau-\tau^{\prime}}{(c\tau+d)(c\tau^{\prime}+d)}. \tag{8'} $$
3. The proposal (2') solves OP's sign problem. Eq. (2') can be somewhat defended by pointing out that

   - the notion of 1D [conformal/angle-preserving transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map) is artificial in the first place, and
   - that similar sign factors are implicit in the notion of 2D conformal/angle-preserving transformations in the complex plane.
4. Conversely, let us consider an arbitrary infinitesimal transformation
   $$ \epsilon(\tau)~=~f(\tau)-\tau
   ~=~\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon_n\tau^n, \qquad
   \epsilon_n~\in~\mathbb{R},\tag{9'} $$
   that leaves the 2-point function (1') invariant. We may assume that
   $$ f^{\prime}(\tau)~=~1 +\epsilon^{\prime}(\tau)~>~0 \tag{10'}$$
   (and its square root) are positive. The linearized invariance condition (2') becomes
   $$ \epsilon^{\prime}(\tau)+\epsilon^{\prime}(\tau^{\prime}) ~=~2\frac{\epsilon(\tau)-\epsilon(\tau^{\prime})}{\tau-\tau^{\prime}}.\tag{11'} $$
   The complete solution to eq. (11') is arbitrary 2nd-order polynomials
   $$ \epsilon(\tau)~=~\sum_{n=0}^2\epsilon_n\tau^n~=~\epsilon_0+\epsilon_1\tau+\epsilon_2\tau^2,\tag{12'} $$
   which precisely corresponds to the infinitesimal form of the $sl(2,\mathbb{R})$ symmetry transformation (3'). This shows that the full symmetry group is [$PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group:PSL(2,R)).

References:

1. V. Rosenhaus, *An intro to SYK,* [arXiv:1807.03334](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03334); eq. (3.3).
2. G. Sarosi, *$AdS_2$ holography and the SYK model,* [arXiv:1711.08482](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08482); eq. (121).
3. J. Maldacena & D. Stanford, *Comments on the SYK model,* [arXiv:1604.07818](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07818); eq. (2.9).

--

$^1$ Note that eq. (1') is odd (and hence not invariant) under time reversal $f(\tau)=-\tau.$ For this reason we only consider time reparametrizations $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f^{\prime}>0$.

$^2$ Note that eq. (4') is invariant under $M\to -M$ in eq. (6). More generally, this proposal is only single-valued for $n$-point functions with $n$ even.